# 401 System.UnauthorizedAccessException when access Dropbox With SharpBox API

Tags: asp.net, dropbox, sharpbox

The code

```
config = CloudStorage.GetCloudConfigurationEasy(nSupportedCloudConfigurations.DropBox) 
    as DropBoxConfiguration;
//config.AuthorizationCallBack = new Uri("http://localhost:61926/DBoxDemo.aspx");

requestToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxRequestToken(config, "KEY", "SECRET");
//Session["requestToken"] = requestToken;

string AuthoriationUrl = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.GetDropBoxAuthorizationUrl(
    config, requestToken);
Process.Start(AuthoriationUrl);
accessToken = DropBoxStorageProviderTools.ExchangeDropBoxRequestTokenIntoAccessToken(
    config, "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", requestToken);

CloudStorage dropBoxStorage = new CloudStorage();

var storageToken = dropBoxStorage.Open(config, accessToken);
var publicFolder = dropBoxStorage.GetFolder("/");

// upload a testfile from temp directory into public folder of DropBox
String srcFile = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"C:\Test\MyTestFile.txt");
var rep = dropBoxStorage.UploadFile(srcFile, publicFolder);
MessageBox.Show("Uploaded Successfully..");

**dropBoxStorage.DownloadFile("/MyTestFile.txt",
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("D:\\test"));**

MessageBox.Show("Downloaded Successfully..");
dropBoxStorage.Close();
```

This is the Error shown in Visual Studio.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When I try to Download It Gives me ERROR Upload Works Fine PLEASE HELP

Comment: Same Code works Fine in Console Application But when i Try to Put it in Web Form or Window Form It Gives Error Unauthorized access in Downloading.

Comment: If uploading works, meaning the access token is valid, but downloading doesn't, it sounds like an issue signing the download calls. I believe SharpBox uses HMAC-SHA1 signing by default. I recommend changing that to PLAINTEXT. (I unfortunately am not that familiar with using SharpBox though, so I don't know how to do so specifically.)

Comment: Yup Problem solved. actually SharpBox only works with .net framwork 4.0 so previously it was 4.5. so i changed it to 4.0 now it works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SharpBox has a bug that only occurs in .NET 4.5, because the behavior of the class `System.Uri` has changed from 4.0 to 4.5.

The method `GetDownloadFileUrlInternal()` in *DropBoxStorageProviderService.cs* generates an incorrect URL, because it changes a slash in **%2f**. In .NET 4.0, this URL will be converted correctly back through the `System.Uri` object in the method `GenerateSignedUrl()` in *OAuthUrlGenerator.cs*.

I have changed the method `GetDownloadFileUrlInternal()` from this...

```cs
public static String GetDownloadFileUrlInternal(IStorageProviderSession session, ICloudFileSystemEntry entry)
{
    // cast varibales
    DropBoxStorageProviderSession dropBoxSession = session as DropBoxStorageProviderSession;

    // gather information
    String rootToken = GetRootToken(dropBoxSession);
    String dropboxPath = GenericHelper.GetResourcePath(entry);

    // add all information to url;
    String url = GetUrlString(DropBoxUploadDownloadFile, session.ServiceConfiguration) + "/" + rootToken;

    if (dropboxPath.Length > 0 && dropboxPath[0] != '/')
        url += "/";

    url += HttpUtilityEx.UrlEncodeUTF8(dropboxPath);

    return url;
}
```

...to this...

```cs
public static String GetDownloadFileUrlInternal(IStorageProviderSession session, ICloudFileSystemEntry entry)
{
    // cast varibales
    DropBoxStorageProviderSession dropBoxSession = session as DropBoxStorageProviderSession;

    // gather information
    String rootToken = GetRootToken(dropBoxSession);

    // add all information to url;
    String url = GetUrlString(DropBoxUploadDownloadFile, session.ServiceConfiguration) + "/" + rootToken;

    ICloudFileSystemEntry parent = entry.Parent;
    String dropboxPath = HttpUtilityEx.UrlEncodeUTF8(entry.Name);

    while(parent != null)
    {
        dropboxPath = HttpUtilityEx.UrlEncodeUTF8(parent.Name) + "/" + dropboxPath;
        parent = parent.Parent;
    }

    if (dropboxPath.Length > 0 && dropboxPath[0] != '/')
        url += "/";

    url += dropboxPath;

    return url;
}
```

and currently it works with .NET 4.5. It may exist a better way to fix the problem, but currently no misconduct noticed.

Comment: We downloaded the source code from https://sharpbox.svn.codeplex.com/svn/, made the changes you suggested and it worked. Only problem is that there is no branch for version 1.2.0.542 - latest is 1.1.0.440 - do you know where to find version 1.2.0.542?